# readyapi/maven integration - couldn't transfer artifact

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, soapui, ready-api

Updating question; I am trying to implement readyapi with maven, followed the steps here https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/integrations/maven/example.html#pom but not able to resolve plugin issue. Any help?

[image]

````
        <repository>
            <id>com.teamdev</id>
            <url>https://europe-maven.pkg.dev/jxbrowser/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!-- Add the SmartBear ReadyAPI plugin repository. -->
    <!-- Maven will download the plugin from the specified URL. -->
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear</groupId>
                <artifactId>ready-api-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>Sample-SOAP-project.xml</projectFile>
                            <readyApiProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>readyAPI</name>
                                    <value>C:\per\ReadyAPI\ReadyAPI-3.0.0\bin</value>
                                </property>
                            </readyApiProperties>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>```
````

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying to integrate maven through pom and it didn't work so I installed packages manually

This is the root cause of the problem. You did so manually and maven can't find them now.

Let's do this the proper way. Create a `pom`, which tries to import the necessary dependencies using `mvn` and then post it here. It will be easier to debug that than to figure out how to add dependencies of the right version manually.

Edit your post with the new pom and post a comment here.

**EDIT**:

OK, so the reason why you are unable to download this stuff from Maven, its because maven blocks blocks external HTTP repositories by default since some version.

Here's a [solution](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html#how-to-fix-when-i-get-a-http-repository-blocked) from the `mvn` team about how to fix this.

Comment: updated question, just a note to my original question: when I try to add plugin manually it gives different error when I run "mvn test", error: "A required class was missing while executing com.smartbear:ready-api-maven-plugin:3.0.0:test: Lcom/eviware/soapui/support/MessageSupport;" @arthur-klezovich

Comment: Cool Can you post the code to Github and send me the link ?

Comment: @Alex see edit to my post about how to solve the issue.

Comment: I changed to https as it says in the solution you shared but still gives the error "Execution default of goal com.smartbear:ready-api-maven-p
lugin:3.0.0:test failed: A required class was missing while executing com.smartbear:ready-api-maven-plugin:3.0.0:test: Lcom/eviware/soapui/support/MessageSupport;
"

Comment: Can you run `mvn install` and tell me what kind of output it gives. It seems to be missing some sources.

Comment: here is the part before the error [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ automation ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- ready-api-maven-plugin:3.0.0:test (default) @ automation ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.eviware.soapui.maven2.TestMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/eviware/soapui/support/MessageSupport;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields (Class.java:2583)